# speed up the downloading of 19,000 records from rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

I have a specific requirement which allows the user to download records for an entire month. This can include a range from 15,000 to 20,000 records. I have an optimized query, but the issue is in the html rendering. Basically, it goes through each record and formats it by time, date, speed, etc. The problem is right now it is taking over 6 minutes to actually render the table with the content on it on an html print window. If I cannot optimize the query or rendering anymore, what other options do I have? (Note there is no point saving the page as a cache because such large quantity of records will only ever be downloaded once per month)

```
#query
@reports = unit.reports.where("reports.time > ? and reports.time < ?",range.begin, range.end)
@reports = @reports.includes(:alerts)


#view rendering:
- @reports.each do |r|
    %tr
      %td.num_col       #{Report.index_of(@reports, r)}
      - if @history_date
        %td.time_col      #{time_format(r.time)}
      - else
        %td.time_col      #{datetime_format(r.time)}
      - if @unit.unit_type.name == "MarineTrac"
        %td.latitude_col #{r.latitude.to_s}
        %td.longitude_col #{r.longitude.to_s}
        %td.address_col{:title => r.address_formatted} #{r.address_formatted(:street => false)}
      - else
        %td.street_col{:title => r.street}  #{r.street}
      %td.speed_col     #{speed_formatted(r)}
      %td.distance_col  #{r.distance}
      - if r.alerts.any?
        %td.alert_col
          %ul{:style => "margin: 0px; padding: 0px; list-style-type: none;"}
            - r.alerts.each do |alert|
              %li
                %span{:class => "#{alert.class_for_severity}"}= alert_full_str(alert)
      - else
        %td.alerts_col{:class => "severity_none"} None
      %td.signal_col #{r.signal_formatted}
      %td.fix_col #{r.gps_valid_str}
```

Comment: What version of Haml do you have bundled?

Comment: You could try slicing the reports so not as much has to be loaded into memory. @reports.find_each(100) do |r|.  That will load the records 100 at a time

Comment: I think the issue is not necessarily haml, but the fact that each of these 20,000 records does reverse geocoding using google maps api - so that means tons of http requests to google or mapquest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend extracting the report generation into a background process.

Basically, use something like [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) to enqueue the report to be generated when the user requests it. You can then return immediately and tell them something like "Your report is now being generated. You will receive an email when it completes."

Your Sidekiq worker would do all the work, and simply shoot off an email to the user when it is done.

Comment: This seems to be the most promising option since the user will click to display 20,000 records and then immediately print it. They will not scroll or anything so using pagination or ajax will not be helpful. Here's the additional catch. Each record will query the google or mapquest or openmaps reverse geocoding api - this request 20,000 times over http surely strains performance. So am I thinking of using Sidekiq or the rails daemon to run constantly in the background to query the entire database and do reverse geocoding record by record. You think that is practical?

Comment: Could I use sidekiq within a rails daemon maybe?

Comment: @JohnMerlino Yeah, 20k external api calls isn't really something you can expect to do during a single request. If you could do the api call for each record as it is created, I think you'd be in much better shape. I would create a Sidekiq job that takes a record id, pulls it out of the database, makes the external api call, and saves that data back into the database with the record. Then I would enqueue this job to run for each record as it is created or updated or whatever. That way, the report just has to render out data you already have in your db, which will be far faster.

Comment: Yes I agree with that and that's what I am doing. Your answer is the best here.

Answer (score 1):

Use pagination to split up the results into manageable chunks, I prefer [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari).

I suspect that you are going to need all the results on a single page. To handle this, you can use pagination along with jQuery [infinite scroll](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll) to load more results as the user scrolls down the page. Not only will this speed up initial page load, but it will put less stress on the server if the user is only looking for the first batch of results, all while keeping everything listed on one page.

Even if loading on scroll isn't an option, you could still use ajax to load each pagination 'page' (say 2,000 results per page?) a section at a time. Or depending on how beefy your server is and how fast you need the results, you could spawn all the required ajax page loads asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

Export it as a CSV they can download.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need it for viewing, you can use pagination so you will render only part of the results each time - For example use the will_paginate gem
2. If you need to display all...try to make it a PDF, I think Prawn gem is a good one for that

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

u should have a look at http://jiren.github.io/StreamTable.js/stream.html. It fetches 'n' records initially, renders the page while simultaneously it keep loading the remaining data from server so that u don't have to wait for the entire data to be loaded for rendering. It also has pagination support and also displays the amount of data currently loaded.